# Facebook v2.1 Obtain access token with permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, oauth-2.0

I had a great way of obtaining an access token with the `publish_actions, manage_pages, and photo_upload` permissions.  I followed the manual workflow from Facebook itself.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1

I used the `scope` parameter to set these permissions.  The problem only occurred recently when I was only getting access tokens that only had `public_profile` permission.  I don't understand how it could work one week and then not the next.

Any ideas or advice.

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing by your self or is someone else testing that doesn't have a role on the app? Before you can ask people that don't have a role on the app you need to get the permission approved. And publish_stream doesn't exists

Comment: Right now my application is still being developed.  So I am the only person that can modify the Facebook App.  I just cant get a manual login workflow for Facebook with the permissions I want.

Comment: I meant public_actions instead of publish_stream

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong when you ask for the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a lot of research it seems that I had the wrong permissions.  I ad been developing this application for the past 8 months or so and apparently in that time Facebook has changed the names of its permissions.  So if your using a manual OAuth workflow for Facebook please make sure your [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1) are valid.